# Recover SMS messages from .backup file

Tags: sms, backup, restore

I have the extracted files from the .backup file created by a phones recovery menu. How do I go about restoring the SMS messages from the mmssms.db and other associated files to another phone? I was able to find a way to convert the contacts2.db file to a .vcf but haven't been able to find a way for the SMS messages.